# No CSI Structure available

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am using an FTP batch script to download a 26mb file and not all the time but sometimes it doesnt complete downloading and I get the error "No CSI Structure Available"? Has anyone seen this or know what it means?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName= 
Set _UserName=
Set _Password=
Set _LocalFolder= C:\Temp
Set _Filename=/Presentation
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
:: Create script
>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo mget %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"

pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are transferring as BINary (Type=I). I had this error from a client and it turns out a cisco router somewhere along the path was trying to translate binary to another charset - the user forgot to specify binary and so the default was character (Type=A). I don't have a CSI structure file on my FTP hence the complaint.

Cured my problem